# REST request works with POSTMAN but not RestClient

Tags: c#, .net, rest, magento, httprequest

I want to use REST api to download orders from my magento websites.

I used https for my website, so when you requesting http, it automatically convert to https.

My REST request is pretty simple, just include token in the http request header, the request works fine with POSTMAN, but with my c# code, it fails consistently.

My RestClient library:

```
 public class RestClient
 {
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public HttpVerb Method { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string PostData { get; set; }
    public string Accept { get; set; }

    public RestClient(string endpoint, HttpVerb method, string postData, string contentType)
    {
        EndPoint = endpoint;
        Method = method;
        ContentType = contentType;
        PostData = postData;
    }

      public string MakeRequest(string parameters, Dictionary<string, string> headers, 
        out HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, out bool succeed)
     {
        httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        succeed = false;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint + parameters);

        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        //request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;
        if (Accept!=null && Accept != "")
            request.Accept = Accept;

        foreach (var entry in headers)
        {
            request.Headers[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && (Method == HttpVerb.POST || Method == HttpVerb.PUT))
        {

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(PostData);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseValue = string.Empty;
                httpStatusCode = response.StatusCode;

                // grab the response
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }

                    }
                }

                succeed = true;
                return responseValue;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return resp;
        }

        return "";
    }
```

My code:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", credential.Token));

        String url = String.Format("{0}/rest/V1/orders?"
            +"searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&"
            +"searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={1}&"
            +"searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&"
            +"searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=updated_at&"
            +"searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]={2}&"
            +"searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to",
            credential.WebsiteURL,
            updateStart.ToString(),
            updateEnd.ToString());

        RestClient client = new RestClient(url, HttpVerb.GET, "", "application/json");

        String respJson = null;
        HttpStatusCode code = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        bool succeed = false;
        try
        {
            respJson = client.MakeRequest("", headers, out code, out succeed);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Does anybody met with before? Thanks!

Comment: Try posting your code - as is this is is not a minimal, complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Adding to @ste-fu 's suggestion, post your REST request code, including any headers you've tried to add, since the problem is usually the auth token.

Comment: How exactly does it fail?  Error?  Timeout?  Exception?

Comment: Not authorized, just like the token was not passed in

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are never setting the `Accept` header anywhere. This is unlikely to cause a Not Authorized error but it's not your api so who knows.

Also you may wish to consider setting the authorization explicitly by passing the token in either the constructor or the `MakeRequest` method, and then using

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", myAuthorizationToken);
```